# Blender Player on Playstation 4 PSVR

Tags: game-engine

Are there any plans, ideas or success stories to run Blender Player on Playstation 4 PSVR? PSVR could be really nice alternative and relatively low cost just after Android Cardboard but much better performance and quality. I don't really want to give up field to Unity. Blender Powers! =)

I am re-editing this post to store information on how Blender could be used with PS4/PSVR gear. Details below:

- Using DS4 PS4 Bluetooth controller with Blender: https://t.co/swDQevV1aJ
- BlenderVR project: https://blendervr.limsi.fr/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be a feature request

Comment: As far as I know Blender Player only runs on Windows, Linux and Mac. And to a much lesser extent a basic Android version

Comment: Blender Player also runs on FreeBSD, and Playstation4 runs on FreeBSD. That would be great development environment for VR applications. We have analyzed performance of BP on Android, it was not satisfactory and did not have PC features. PS4VR on the other hand seems to be next system in the row and price level..

Comment: How running BLENDER on a new hardware/platform seems to be off "blender" topic for you folks? hahah =)

Comment: Here is BlenderVR project: https://blendervr.limsi.fr/doku.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Blender Player only runs on Windows, Linux and Mac. And to a much lesser extent a basic Android version.

Did not know about FreeBSD on PlayStation though, but on Android it was pretty much a proof of concept. It's feature incomplete and experimental, without any kind of support or continued development.

Have in mind however that the Blender player is  sort of a dead end. It is considered [old and outdated](https://code.blender.org/2013/06/blender-roadmap-2-7-2-8-and-beyond/), and development has sort of stalled. It is also [considered for removal for the future Blender versions](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NjuEd3Dw7chJ9OyViyJn3MWQPcc6-zQM4yGFxuVFEfo/edit#gid=0)

A much more modern and future proof technology would be browser based WebGL technologies which have good support in every modern browser and mobile platforms and also have some extent of VR Support.

[Blend4Web is a great Blender Addon](http://www.blend4web.com/) which removes much of the need for coding, while being open source and free for personal use.

Comment: Is there any alternative for Blender Player that I could use instead to play *.blend files? I assume it will be Blender4Web? Is it fully featured player replacement.. or planned to be?

Comment: Blend4Web is not a replacement for the Game Engine nor intents to be. Its third party developed, not as full featured (yet) nor can it play Blend files directly. It used either HTML files or JSON files, and has it's own logic system which despite being more rudimentary in some ways is also a lot more advanced and powerful in others like being node based.

Comment: I suggest to focus on the answer rather than distributing incorrect rumors that do not belong to the topic. The blender player can't be outdated as it is the current BGE. It is the code that runs inside Blender.

Answer (score 0):

No. As Duarte mentioned, Blender Player does not run on the PlayStation Operating System. There are no mentions of this feature in development, either.

Comment: Thanks. We can leave this topic for other people interested in this subject. Maybe someone would have more to say or present :-)