# Blender Game for Mobile Device

Tags: import, unity

Is there a way I can import a game from the Blender Game engine to both an iPhone or Android, whether it's using a different program or not? If not possible, is there a way I can import everything in that specific Blender file over to Unity without changing any of the textures (all image textures, since they were baked), locations of the objects, and settings for the lamps/cameras/etc.? Help is greatly appreciated.
(Not a VR game)

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65454/blender-player-on-playstation-4-psvr/65557#65557

Comment: It doesn't really matter whether this is VR game or not, it does matter which end devices are you going to orient. If your question is about what game engine to use for Android and iPhone support then Unity will work. You do not need specific Blender file format (.blend) to transfer objects to game engine; if textures are baked and you know how to setup game engine materials it won't be a problem.

Comment: Alright, I have little experience with Unity so I might watch some tutorials. I thought there might have been an easier way, you know - like just simply pressing a button and the whole blender file is imported to Unity without changing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a project called BlenderPlayer for Android, which let you run .blend files and even develop games on an Android device:

https://www.blendernation.com/2012/06/26/blenderplayer-for-android/

But this has been discontinued. I'm not aware of any other way to export Blender games as mobile apps.

You might also want to research this, but I'm sorry I don't know more detail about it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U8RzsJfh3Gc